# Alternative to Crystal Reports in Azure PAAS (app model)

Tags: azure, crystal-reports

We are migrating to Azure platform as a service, and it looks like we can't use Crystal Reports.  We use CR to generate PDFs based on the rpt files.  I want to see if there is any low code tools out there that have a visual designer than will allow database data (or JSON data) and generate a PDF.

I know we can work around this by using HTML and convert to PDF (this isn't ideal).  I also know we can use Power BI, I'm looking to see if there Power BI alternatives (just to have a range of possibilities).

Edit this is for a .NET Framework MVC C# application.

Comment: You can use DevExpress Reporting.